# React map through two arrays without duplication

Tags: arrays, reactjs, mapping

I have problem that I gotta make table which is divided on half at the beginning shows left side and middle Ids, then after receiving data from api request, it compares these two arrays and mark differences on red. Actually it works partly good, so it map through 2 arrays, and if it finds any differences then color it on red, the problem is that it also duplicates all elements and in the end table has double same rows several times. I understand that it is because I'm mapping array inside another mapping but I don't have idea how to solve this problem. Basic idea is: Show all results without duplication, and mark differences. I know how to mark differences but totally have no idea how to not show duplicates Here I post minimized code for easier reading Thanks!

```
   const applicationsTable = (classes, current, compared) =>
  current.configuration.applications.map((el, i) => 
      compared &&
      compared.configuration.applications.map((comparedEl, i) => (

        <TableRow key={i}>
          <StyledFiledTableCell>
            <Typography variant="body2">
            {el.version}

            </Typography>
          </StyledFiledTableCell>

          <StyledFiledTableCell colSpan="5">
            <Typography variant="body2">{el.aid}</Typography>
          </StyledFiledTableCell>

          {el.aid == comparedEl.aid ? (
            <>
              <StyledFiledTableCell>
                <Typography variant="body2">
                {comparedEl.version}

                </Typography>
              </StyledFiledTableCell>

            </>
          ) : (
            <StyledFiledTableCell colSpan="5" />
          )}
        </TableRow>
      ))
    )
```

here I post also photo of my problem, as you can see, elements in table are duplicated 
[image]

and here is example of my compared and current data:

```
const current.configuration.applications = [
    {
      aid: "E82B0601040181C31F0201",
      lifeCycle: "SELECTABLE",
      version: null
    },
    {
      aid: "E82B0601040181C31F027F0301",
      lifeCycle: "SELECTABLE",
      version: null
    },
    {
      aid: "D2760001725041636301",
      lifeCycle: "SELECTABLE",
      version: null
    },
    {
      aid: "D276000172536F434D01",
      lifeCycle: "SELECTABLE",
      version: null
    },
  ]

  const compared.configuration.applications = [
    {
      aid: "E82B0601040181C31F0201",
      lifeCycle: "SELECTABLE",
      version: "03.02"
    },
    {
      aid: "D276000172536F434D01",
      lifeCycle: "SELECTABLE",
      version: "02.07"
    },
  ]
```

Comment: you can try lodash `uniq` method

Comment: hmm could you give some example? as I kinda don't know how to implement lodash in my case

Comment: hmm I don't quite understand your algorithm above. Are you trying to find the differences between two arrays based on `aid` value, and show them on a table?

Comment: my issue is, I have two arrays which I get from two different api responses. First one is named current, another one is named compared. I wish to loop and display them in tables as shown above. long number is aid, on the left I wish to display version from current, on the right side I wish to display version of compared. (if it is null then I don't display it) anyway as you can see after double looping, row with aid gets duplicated, I wish to get rid of any duplicated row

Comment: ah. so you want to map the `version` from another array to the left array? Let me rephrase your intention: you want to display `current` list on the left hand side of the table, and on the right hand side, find the `version` value from `compared` list, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I exactly understand your problem. But if you have **input data** like this:

```
const current = { configuration: {} };
current.configuration.applications = [
    {
        aid: "1",
        lifeCycle: "SELECTABLE",
        version: null
    },
    {
        aid: "2",
        lifeCycle: "SELECTABLE",
        version: null
    },
    {
        aid: "3",
        lifeCycle: "SELECTABLE",
        version: null
    },
    {
        aid: "4",
        lifeCycle: "SELECTABLE",
        version: null
    },
];

const compared = { configuration: {} };
compared.configuration.applications = [
    {
        aid: "1",
        lifeCycle: "SELECTABLE",
        version: "03.02"
    },
    {
        aid: "4",
        lifeCycle: "SELECTABLE",
        version: "02.07"
    },
];
```

By using this code you will get unique values of current and compared + duplicate values will be merged and marked by `colorRed: true`

```
const merged = current.configuration.applications.map((item, index) => {
    if (compared) {
        const findCompared = compared.configuration.applications.find((e) => e.aid === item.aid, index);
        if (typeof findCompared !== "undefined") {
            return {
                ...item, ...findCompared, colorRed: true
            };
        }
    }
    return item;
});
```

Then **result array** will be like this:

```
// merged =>
[
  {
    "aid": "1",
    "lifeCycle": "SELECTABLE",
    "version": "03.02",
    "colorRed": true
  },
  {
    "aid": "2",
    "lifeCycle": "SELECTABLE",
    "version": null
  },
  {
    "aid": "3",
    "lifeCycle": "SELECTABLE",
    "version": null
  },
  {
    "aid": "4",
    "lifeCycle": "SELECTABLE",
    "version": "02.07",
    "colorRed": true
  }
]
```

So you just can go through `merged` by `.map()` and display all the data.

*P.S.: I changed 'aid' to make the example simpler, but you can use it with your data.*

Comment: it works! That's not exactly what I meant but your solution got me idea and now it works fine! Thank you so much for help

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use another method, not another map() in side the outer loop. 
Try using Array.prototype.find() and give the map() a condition if you can find a dup.

Comment: but the problem is that sometimes aid is going to be same with current and compared data and just gotta replace other values, sometimes in compared data is aid which current doesn't contain and then gotta add it, so find might to not work

Comment: lol I should have be more clear on this. But a find() method works right?

Comment: yep, just I couldn't get idea how to implement it, but your idea was good! Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you want to display the `version` value on the `compared` list for the same application ID. If I am right, then you actually don't need two `.map()` function, what you need is a `.find()` method:

```
const applicationsTable = (classes, current, compared) =>
  current.configuration.applications.map((el, i) => {
    const comparedEl = compared.configuration.applications.find(comparedEl => comparedEl.aid === el.aid);
    return (
      <TableRow key={i}>
        <StyledFiledTableCell>
          <Typography variant="body2">
            {el.version}
          </Typography>
        </StyledFiledTableCell>

        <StyledFiledTableCell colSpan="5">
          <Typography variant="body2">
            {el.aid}
          </Typography>
        </StyledFiledTableCell>

        {
          comparedEl ? (
          <>
            <StyledFiledTableCell>
              <Typography variant="body2">
                {comparedEl.version}
              </Typography>
            </StyledFiledTableCell>
          </>
          ) : (
          <StyledFiledTableCell colSpan="5" />
          )
        }
      </TableRow>
    );
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks my friend for all help:) indeed proper using of find() was a key. Thank you for all help:)

Comment: @Jacki glad you found the solution! no worries! (y)